# Elixir - How to convert keyword list to string?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a keyword list: `[key1: "value", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"]`

I want to convert it into a string: `"key1:value1&key2:value2&key3:value3"`

I was thinking to use Enum.reduce, but what will be the arguments to the function?

Answer (score 6):

Since you want to add a separator *between* the values after mapping them, I'd suggest using `Enum.map_join/3`:

```elixir
    iex(1)> list = [key1: "value", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"]
    [key1: "value", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"]
    iex(2)> list |> Enum.map_join("&", fn {k, v} -> "#{k}:#{v}" end)
    "key1:value&key2:value2&key3:value3"
```

This is how you can do it with `Enum.reduce/3` (There's an extra `&` inserted at the start which is being removed using `String.trim_leading/1`):

```elixir
    iex(3)> list |> Enum.reduce("", fn {k, v}, acc -> "#{acc}&#{k}:#{v}" end) |> String.trim_leading("&")
    "key1:value&key2:value2&key3:value3"
```

Comment: Using @dogbert's solutions, and and a few of my own, I did some super informal benchmarking [in this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/amorphid/9bd536cfe19d2a3230c61a349b615aab).  When running it with 3 million elements, I crashed the BEAM with too many atoms :)

Comment: The beams default limit of 1m atoms can be adjusted using the [`+t`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) flag.